# SVM without SGD in Spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, classification, svm, apache-spark-mllib, gradient-descent

I have come across the SVMwithSGD implementation in MLLib in Spark 2.0.2. 
Just curious to know whether there is any implementation of an SVM classifier without SGD in Spark 2.0.2.

If not, is there any way in which I can implement SVM in Spark?

NB: What I really want to do is compare the performance of SVM to SVMwithSGD.